# While testing my google assistant app in the Google Assistant simulator, it's not identifying the intent, but it's working in web demo and dialog flow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am developing a google assistant app I created the conversation and tested in Web Demo, Dialog flow, it's working fine and giving the proper response, but while testing in a google assistant simulator, it's only identifying the default welcome intent and it's unable to find the next intent information for more information review the below screen cast

https://www.screencast.com/t/qNJXhrjcB

Comment: So if you pay attention there are two tabs under response 'Default' and 'Google assistant'. Try making the changes you wish in the 'Google assistant' tab and then run it with your simulator, remember to update to the newest test version. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply when I am trying with gmail account, it's working fine, but when am doing with other domain it's not giving me proper result